# Library assets not compiling when publishing for AIR

Tags: actionscript-3

Yesterday I started messing around with Adobe Scout. It gave me a message that said that my function times are not accurate because I'm running a debug mode (in a file that is compiling as an AIR app) and to try compiling a published version first. Thus began my foray into the exciting world of AIR certificates and Windows Installer packages. I made certificate, published it, opened the published package, installed it, opened the resulting file, and found... *fanfare* ... a rectangle object I draw with AS3 and nothing else. When I test the movie (debug version) in AIR, it has the rectangle as well as a 20x20 map of tiles that are created at runtime from a bitmap that is blitted into 16x16 tiles.

Huh? Do I need to do something special when publishing for AIR to embed the library item? Anyone have this issue publishing to AIR where library assets are unavailable at runtime?

Of course I'll post code if anyone thinks they would like to see it, but it all works fine in flash player, fine (albeit slow) in Adobe AIR for Desktop (when testing), just missing library assets when published and installed via Windows installer.

**update**

for that matter, when I publish a swf for playback on the web or flash player, a similar thing: just a colored background (per my .fla file settings) but no rectangle and no blitted bmp tiles.  Could I be executing code before something is loaded, and when it is in a debug mode, the setup takes longer, so things have time to get loaded before trying to execute?  I've tried to avoid this, but maybe failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently making an .exe file or AIR app doesn't stand alone from the library components.  Their is probably a way to embed them in the project, but for my purposes, I found that just making sure that the .exe and necessary .png files are in the same source file solved the issue.  The problem was that my .exe file was automatically getting compiled and saved into a different folder, so I thought that folder must have all the needed files in it.

So, the bottom line is just that an .exe or AIR file, when published, won't automatically have the needed files in the right places.  It still needs to point to the correct file location for those files.